# Makefile error: /bin/sh: 1: /dir Permission denied

Tags: makefile, sh

When running make I have the following compilation error:

**/bin/sh: 1: /installed/CoinAll/include/coin: Permission denied**

This is the Makefile:

```
#
P=farmer
#

EXE=$(P)
OBJS=main-farmer.o model-farmer.o param-farmer.o pm.h

ADDLIBS=-D.
ADDINCFLAGS=-I.

SRCDIR=~/coin-projects

########## 


CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wimplicit -Wparentheses -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion
CXXLINKFLAGS=-Wl,--rpath -Wl,/installed/CoinAll/lib
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-03 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wimplicit -Wparentheses -Wsequence-point -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall


COININCDIR=/installed/CoinAll/include/coin

#  COIN-OR libs
COINLIBDIR=/installed/CoinAll/lib

#  Clp
LIBS=-L$(COINLIBDIR) -lCbc -lCgl -lOsiClp -lOsi -lClp -lCoinUtils -lm \
`cat $(COINLIBDIR)/cgl_addlibs.txt` \
`cat $(COINLIBDIR)/clp_addlibs.txt` \
`cat $(COINLIBDIR)/coinutils_addlibs.txt` 

INCL=-I`$(CYGPATH_W)$(COININCDIR)`$(ADDINCFLAGS)

CYGPATH_W=




CLEANFILES=\
addBits.o addBits \
addColumns.o addColumns \
addRows.o addRows \
decompose.o decompose \
defaults.o defaults \
driver2.o driver2 \
driver.o driver \
driverC.o driverC \
dualCuts.o dualCuts \
ekk.o ekk \
ekk_interface.o ekk_interface \
hello.o hello \
makeDual.o makeDual \
minimum.o minimum \
network.o network \
piece.o piece \
rowColumn.o rowColumn \
sprint2.o sprint2 \
sprint.o sprint \
testBarrier.o testBarrier \
testBasis.o testBasis \
testGub2.o testGub2 \
testGub.o testGub \
testQP.o testQP \
useVolume.o useVolume

# Part 3
#

all: $(EXE)
.SUFFIXES: .cpp .c .o .obj
$(EXE):$(OBJS)
bla=;
for file in $(OBJS); do bla="$$bla `$(CYGPATH_W) $$file`"; done; \
$(CXX) $(CXXLINKFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $$bla $(ADDLIBS) $(LIBS)

####
########
############
########
####


clean:
    rm -rf $(CLEANFILES)
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<
.cpp.obj:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `if test -f '$<'; then $(CYGPATH_W) '$<'; else $(CYGPATH_W) '$(SRCDIR)/$<'; fi`
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<
.c.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `if test -f '$<'; then $(CYGPATH_W) '$<'; else $(CYGPATH_W) '$(SRCDIR)/$<'; fi`
```

I have set the permissions as rwx for /installed/CoinAll/include/coin and for all of its files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as if the Makefile is trying to execute the program /installed/CoinAll/include/coin which instead is a directory. It does not matter how you chmod a directory, it will still not be possible to execute as a program.

The following line:
INCL=-I`$(CYGPATH_W)$(COININCDIR)`$(ADDINCFLAGS)

in combination with lines like this:
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<

... will evaluate to commands like:

g++ (a lot of c++-flags) -I`installed/CoinAll/include/coin` -c -o...

as both $(CYGPATH_W) and $(ADDINCFLAGS) are empty.

When the shell executes a command containing backticks "`"it will replace the text between the backticks with the output from the command between the backticks. Try this:
echo `ls /`

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and it was my anti-virus. Turned on, I get the same error you do. Off, it works just fine. Then turning the anti-virus back on, same error as you get. It was my anti-virus so try turning all it's features off temporarily.